# Is it possible to set DNS on MacOS by hostname?

Tags: dns, macos-bigsur

It is possible to set a custom DNS on MacOS with an IP address. However, I have a custom DNS in my LAN that I use instead, with the hostname `hostname.local`. Is there a way to get MacOS to use `hostname.local` instead of an IP address, as the IP of the DNS can change. This hostname is reachable through MacOS's Bonjour. I can not directly modify the router, everything must be done on my device.

Comment: This is the kind of info you should be setting at your gateway, so all DHCP clients can use it.

Comment: I don't have any control over the gateway.

Comment: Then you ought to provide that kind of detail in your question,